# Request on demand of R data from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, r, d3.js, request, shiny

I'm using R for statistical analysis and JavaScript / D3 for visualization. The packages shiny and htmlwidgets allow me for passing data as JSON objects to D3. This works fine.

D3 usually visualizes a snippet of the dataset that can be further explored. Take the example of a collapsible tree, https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083. In my case, the tree can be fully loaded but the data on every node is bigger than just the name, thus I want to load it on demand.

I wonder whether one can load R data lazily. D3 allows entering and exiting nodes, and within these nodes you can include requests such as

```
d3.csv("http://localhost:port/node1.csv")
```

Is there an R package that can work with such XMLHttpRequests? Or do I need to export data first into a directory and provide a HTTPServer on it?

Thank you!

Comment: Since you are using `shiny` as your "webserver", I've added that tag.  `d3` just knows how to make async requests for data (json, csv, etc..), it's up to your webserver to serve that back to it.

Comment: Note that Shiny Server serves files in the `www` subfolder of your project via http, so you can probably make use of that.

Comment: I'm still not clear on expectations.  I think the answer is yes, but hard to answer with the minimal level of detail provided. Do you expect to load additional detail in the popup/tooltip, load additional depth/layer on expand?  Is the data big enough to warrant this additional api/backend call?  How big?